# imported git submodule causing run-time linking errors in Typescript project

Tags: typescript, import, node-modules, git-submodules

Typescript Project A imports Typescript Project B, however I am actively modifying Project B at the same time as working on Project A.

Project A and B each have their own git repo.
I have added Project B as a git submodule to Project A

```
/project-a/
    /src/
       /index.ts
    /build/
       /index.js
    /test/
    /node_modules/
    /project-b/  <- git submodule
       /src
       /build/
       /node_modules
```

Inside index.ts

```
import { classB } from '../project-b/src/classB';
```

I can build Project B independently and I can build Project A with Project B included in tsconfig.json, however at run time node can't find the modules from Project B which are in Project B's node_modules directory.

I have tried using yarn workspaces where both Project A and Project B are the workspaces, however doing that results in Project A no longer being able to be built due to a bunch of build errors coming from Project B which weren't there before.

What is the correct way to set this up?

**Update:**
One example would be that project-b has a dependency on 'winston' logger npm module. `yarn install` in project-b folder will download winston package to `project-b/node_modules`. I then `yarn run build` in `project-a` folder and the project builds successfully with no errors. If I then run `node build/index.js` in `project-a` folder it says that 'winston' module cannot be loaded. As a hacky fix I am adding this dependency to `project-a` which fixes the runtime error but I would rather not add all dependencies of `project-b` to `project-a`. I think the problem is that if this were a javascript project it would find `project-b/node_modules` directory but because in typescript the javascript lives in `build/` there is no `project-b/node_modules` folder in the folder tree.

Comment: What is the path of the file that is trying and failing to load a module from project B's node_modules?  Normally this should just work.

Comment: @MattMcCutchen I added an update to the post to try and provide an example of where the issue is seen.

Comment: Is your build of project A transpiling project B's source code into project A's `build` directory?  If so, that would definitely cause the problem.  Consider using [project references](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html) so that project B will transpile into its own output directory.  You may then have to fiddle with compiler options and/or package.json files so that your import paths work for both the source and the output.

Comment: @MattMcCutchen Yes at the moment Project A is building both A and B into A's build directory. I would like to keep them both independent. Is the normal behavior to have a pre-build step that builds the dependency projects? In which case, should project A be using `import X from ../project-b/some/folder` or `import X from ../project-b/build/src/some/folder` and then rely on the source maps. I still want to be able to import the typescript files and not the javascript compiled source so that all the typescript declarations are intact.

Comment: A project reference gives you just such a "pre-build step" when you use `tsc -b .`.  `import X from '../project-b/build/src/some/folder'` should work because TypeScript will create a `.d.ts` file in `project-b/build/src/some/folder` when it runs on `project-b`.  It's a [known limitation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html#caveats-for-project-references) that you have to build before that import will resolve in your IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Answer provided in comments:

> A project reference gives you just such a "pre-build step" when you use tsc -b .. import X from '../project-b/build/src/some/folder' should work because TypeScript will create a .d.ts file in project-b/build/src/some/folder when it runs on project-b. It's a known limitation that you have to build before that import will resolve in your IDE. – Matt McCutchen 14 hours ago